# Размер объекта класса

Tags: c++, классы, виртуальная-функция

Почему объект класса B=16, а объект A=4? Как влияет виртуальная функция на размер?

```
class A
{
    void funcA();
    int x;
};

class B
{
    virtual void funcB();
    int y;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

На размер влияет не сама по себе виртуальная функция, а ее наличие - а именно наличие указателя на *таблицу виртуальных функций*, необходимую для реализации динамического полиморфизма..

Судя по результатам, вы компилировали 64-разрядное приложение :)

**Update**

Почему 16, а не 12... Итак, VC++, 64-разрадное приложение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    void funcA();
    int x;
};

class B
{
    virtual void funcB();
    int y;
};

#pragma pack(1)
class C
{
    virtual void funcB();
    int y;
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << sizeof(A) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(B) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(C) << endl;
}
```

Получаем:

```
4
16
12
```

Comment: `class A { int y; double x; };
class B { double m; double n; };`
Почему размеры объектов этих классов равны(16), я ожидал что у A=4+8=12

Comment: @Aaas, тут выравнивание полей  так реализован

Comment: @Harry, С Новым Годом, здоровья и  всех благ вам. Искренне вас уважающий

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вам того же!

Comment: Посмотрите по поводу 12/16 обновленный ответ. Это комментарий к комментарию :) ARHovsepyan о выравнивании.

Answer (score 4):

Контекстное окружение должна уметь определять какая именно реализация вызывается(это реализация метода класса `В` или какого то наследника?). Для этого создается таблица виртуальных функций, и каждый обьект имеет неявный указатель на эту таблицу. В стандартах C++ нет четкого определения как должна реализовываться динамическая координация, но компиляторы зачастую используют некоторые вариации одной и той же базовой модели:
Конкретно экземпляры класса `В` будут иметь:

- указатель на виртуальную функцию(`vptr`)-64 битового приложения это
  `8` байт
- тип `int`  _ выравнивается по размеру `vptr` _ тоже 8 байт.

Итог 16 байт